# How to operate two set of tabs separately in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to operate different sets of tabs separately but it is not working properly. Tab 1, 2, and 3 belong to the first set of tabs whereas Tab A, B, and C belong to the second set of tabs. Tab 1 and Tab A should be opened by default when the page is loaded.

What are the necessary changes to be made to achieve the goal?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.tab1 button.active {
  background-color: #03a1fc;
}
.tab2 button.active {
  background-color: #03a1fc;
}
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class = "tab1">
  <button class = "tablinks" id="defaultOpen1" onclick="openTab1(event, 't11')">1</button>
  <button class = "tablinks" onclick="openTab1(event, 't12')">2</button>
  <button class = "tablinks" onclick="openTab1(event, 't13')">3</button>
</div>

<div id="t11" class="tabcontent">
  <p>tab 1</p>
</div>

<div id="t12" class="tabcontent">
  <p>tab 2</p> 
</div>

<div id="t13" class="tabcontent">
  <p>tab 3</p>
</div>


<br><br><br>
<div class = "tab2">
  <button class = "tablinks" id="defaultOpen2" onclick="openTab2(event, 'tA')">A</button>
  <button class = "tablinks" onclick="openTab2(event, 'tB')">B</button>
  <button class = "tablinks" onclick="openTab2(event, 'tC')">C</button>
</div>

<div id="tA" class="tabcontent">
  <p>tab A</p>
</div>

<div id="tB" class="tabcontent">
  <p>tab B</p> 
</div>

<div id="tC" class="tabcontent">
  <p>tab C</p>
</div>


<script>
function openTab1(evt, tabName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

function openTab2(evt, tabName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

document.getElementById("defaultOpen1").click();  
document.getElementById("defaultOpen2").click(); 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: instead firing click on both of your defaut tab, use defaut classes right on tag supposed to  open and style it from css. active for the tab and tabcontent defaut (or else) to the one to be shown., then when you click, it searches for any tabcontent class, so at the first click, only one left will remain shown. You can use query selectors to look for class only behind a single div with a class name starting with tab ... so only the folllowing tabs will be hidden and the one choosen  shown. Also, it will be easier to add/remove a class on the tabcontent class than add/remove style ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I agree with you wholeheartedly. It would shorten the code and make it cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a possibility...

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button.tablinks').forEach(bt => 
  {
  bt.onclick = e =>
    {
    let btGroup = bt.closest('div')
    btGroup.querySelectorAll('button.tablinks').forEach( gBt => 
      gBt.classList.toggle('active', gBt===bt))
      
    btGroup.querySelectorAll('div.tabcontent').forEach( gDv => 
      gDv.classList.toggle('open', gDv.id===bt.dataset.tab))
    }
  })
```

```css
button.active {
  background-color: #03a1fc;
}
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
}
.tabcontent.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="tablinks active" data-tab="t11">1</button>
  <button class="tablinks" data-tab="t12">2</button>
  <button class="tablinks" data-tab="t13">3</button>

  <div id="t11" class="tabcontent open">
    <p>tab 1</p>
  </div>

  <div id="t12" class="tabcontent">
    <p>tab 2</p> 
  </div>

  <div id="t13" class="tabcontent">
    <p>tab 3</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <button class="tablinks active" data-tab="t21">A</button>
  <button class="tablinks" data-tab="t22">B</button>
  <button class="tablinks" data-tab="t23">C</button>

  <div id="t21" class="tabcontent open">
    <p>tab A</p>
  </div>

  <div id="t22" class="tabcontent">
    <p>tab B</p> 
  </div>

  <div id="t23" class="tabcontent">
    <p>tab C</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah. I like it. is a good alternative

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Your programmatic structure needs to be adapted somewhat for this goal. It is best to work with two different tab selectors. I have renamed the first selector tablinks to tablinks1. This way both are displayed.

```js
function openTab1(evt, tabName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent1");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}


function openTab2(evt, tabName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

function init() {
  
}
document.getElementById("defaultOpen1").click();  
document.getElementById("defaultOpen2").click();
```

```css
.tab1 button.active {
  background-color: #03a1fc;
}
.tab2 button.active {
  background-color: #03a1fc;
}
.tabcontent, .tabcontent1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class = "tab1">
  <button class = "tablinks" id="defaultOpen1" onclick="openTab1(event, 't11')">1</button>
  <button class = "tablinks" onclick="openTab1(event, 't12')">2</button>
  <button class = "tablinks" onclick="openTab1(event, 't13')">3</button>
</div>

<div id="t11" class="tabcontent1">
  <p>tab 1</p>
</div>

<div id="t12" class="tabcontent1">
  <p>tab 2</p> 
</div>

<div id="t13" class="tabcontent1">
  <p>tab 3</p>
</div>


<br><br><br>
<div class = "tab2">
  <button class = "tablinks" id="defaultOpen2" onclick="openTab2(event, 'tA')">A</button>
  <button class = "tablinks" onclick="openTab2(event, 'tB')">B</button>
  <button class = "tablinks" onclick="openTab2(event, 'tC')">C</button>
</div>

<div id="tA" class="tabcontent">
  <p>tab A</p>
</div>

<div id="tB" class="tabcontent">
  <p>tab B</p> 
</div>

<div id="tC" class="tabcontent">
  <p>tab C</p>
</div>
```